# Trailing delimiter string splicing, implemented for Lua in C

Tags: performance, c, strings, lua, ffi

I've been writing with C for a couple days, so this is a relatively advanced function compared to the simple things I've been doing previously. It's written for the Lua API, but it's still C.

```c
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int l_rtrim(lua_State *L) {
  luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TSTRING);
  luaL_checktype(L, 2, LUA_TSTRING);

  const char *string = lua_tostring(L, 1);
  const char *delimiter = lua_tostring(L, 2);

  if (*string == '\0') {
    lua_rotate(L, -2, 1);
    return 1;
  }

  size_t len = strlen(string);
  size_t dlCnt = 0;
  size_t tmpLen = len - 1;

  if (tmpLen <= 0) {
    lua_rotate(L, -2, 1);
    return 1;
  }

  char *copy = malloc(len + 1);

  if (copy == NULL) {
    lua_pushstring(L, "out of memory");
    lua_error(L);
    return 1;
  }

  memcpy(copy, string, len + 1);
  while (copy[tmpLen--] == *delimiter) dlCnt++;

  if (dlCnt > 0) {
    size_t location = len - dlCnt;

    if (location > 0) {
      copy[location] = '\0';
      lua_pushstring(L, copy);
    }
    else { /* the entire string is composed of the delimiter */
      lua_pushliteral(L, "");
    }
  }
  free(copy);
  return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg exports[] = {
  {"rtrim", l_rtrim},
  {NULL, NULL}
};

extern __declspec(dllexport) int luaopen_MyModule(lua_State *L) {
  luaL_newlib(L, exports);
  return 1;
}
```

My function counts how many delimiters trail on the right side, so I can insert a null-terminator before any of those delimiters arrive. It's very inefficient (2.5x slower) compared to my implementation of left-trimming (leading spaces) because in that, I just perform a pointer increment.

My main interest is avoiding UB (because I'm not familiar for when it's invoked) and if there's a method I can use to avoid creating a new string & performing so many allocations & copying during benchmarking. I played around a lot with pointer decrementing but it's not working the way I hoped.

Some example inputs and outputs:

```
("??hello world??", "?") -> "??hello world"
("   hello world   ", " ") -> "   hello world"
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you also include a few example inputs and outputs to illustrate what the desired behavior is?

Comment: You seem to be missing some necessary header includes.  It will help reviewers if they can see a *complete* source file.

Comment: @TobySpeight Sure, I can edit the necessary headers, but the complete file is several hundred lines and I only want a review on this function because my instinct tells me it can be greatly improved :)

Comment: @200_success I've added a couple. I added the module registration code too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Unexpected output

Your code returns the original string if it consists of a single delimiter character:

```
rtrim(".", ".")  --> "."
```

I find that illogical. If it is the wanted behavior then it should probably be documented. Otherwise remove the

```
size_t tmpLen = len - 1;
if (tmpLen <= 0) {
    lua_rotate(L, -2, 1);
    return 1;
}
```

part.

#### Undefined behavior

```
while (copy[tmpLen--] == *delimiter) dlCnt++;
```

may access memory “before” the start of the string if the string consists only of the delimiter character.

I would always enclose if/while/for blocks in curly parentheses, even if they consist of a single statement.

#### A bug

If the string does not end with the delimiter character then the delimiter is returned instead of the original string:

```
rtrim("abc", ".") --> "."
```

The reason is that if `dlCnt == 0` then no result string is pushed onto the stack.

#### Embedded zeros

Lua strings can contain arbitrary bytes, including the null byte. But

```
size_t len = strlen(string);
```

treats the null byte as a delimiter, as it would be appropriate for C strings:

```
rtrim("abc.def.\0def...", ".") --> "abc.def"
```

The fix is to use

```
size_t len = lua_rawlen(L, 1);
```

instead, or

```
size_t len;
const char *string = lua_tolstring(L, 1, &len);
```

#### Return the original string if possible

Your code returns the original string if that is empty, thereby avoiding the copy and possible allocation in `lua_pushstring()`:

```
if (*string == '\0') {
    lua_rotate(L, -2, 1);
    return 1;
}
```

Well, I had to think twice in order to understand how it works, I would perhaps write it as

```
if (*string == '\0') {
    // Pop delimiter from stack and return original string:
    lua_pop(L, 1);
    return 1;
}
```

In addition, the same logic could be applied not only for empty string, but generally if the string does not end with the delimiter string.

#### Avoiding the copy

Pushing the truncated string onto the stack does not require null termination if one uses `lua_pushlstring` instead, so that the source string need not be copied and modified.

#### Putting it all together

... we get the following function, which is simpler, less memory-consuming, and does not suffer from the mentioned bugs:

```
static int l_rtrim(lua_State *L) {
    luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TSTRING);
    luaL_checktype(L, 2, LUA_TSTRING);

    size_t len;
    const char *string = lua_tolstring(L, 1, &len);
    const char *delimiter = lua_tostring(L, 2);
    
    size_t trimmed_len = len;
    while (trimmed_len > 0 && string[trimmed_len - 1] == *delimiter) {
        trimmed_len--;
    }

    if (trimmed_len < len) {
        // Push and return trimmed string:
        lua_pushlstring(L, string, len);
    } else {
        // Pop delimiter from stack and return original string:
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the criticism and advice. I've taken it well and reimplemented a much more readable, smaller, and faster solution. Performance went up 16% & readability is through the roof. `lua_pushlstring` does internally perform a copy however, I don't think I can avoid that without messing up the internalized string Lua stores.